# Append PNG/TIFF to existing NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: swift, macos

I have a NSBitmapImageRep which is rendered dynamically in my Swift program and I would like to read and tile a PNG image to the right hand side of the NSBitmapImageRep.

For example, the NSBitmapImageRep looks like:

[image]

And a I have a PNG file like:

[image]

Given that, I'm trying to

1. Extend the width original NSBitmapImageRep by an amount equal to the width of the PNG file
2. Adding white background pixels to the right side
3. Load the PNG file
4. Copy/composite the pixels of the PNG file to the existing NSBitmapImageRep

The final output should look like:

[image]

I've done a lot of searching but can't find a straightforward explanation.
I found the [`bitmapData` method of the `NSBitmapImageRep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbitmapimagerep/1395421-bitmapdata) class. Is the best approach to copy pixel-by-pixel from the two images into a third, larger image?
Or is there already a way to do it with a few simple functions?

Any advice?

**NOTE:** The target is a MacOS command line program. Not iOS.

**EDIT I**

From the link from Willeke was helpful but it is incomplete: it *overlays* two identical images.  I need to *tile* images of different sizes.

Furthermore, the key line in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468138/blend-two-nsimages-using-swift-on-os-x) *does not compile*. Specifically:

```
srcImg.drawInRect(destRect, fromRect: destRect, operation: .CompositeSourceOver, fraction: 1.0)
```

Give two errors:

- Missing arguments for parameters 'respectFlipped', 'hints' in call
- Type 'NSCompositingOperation' has no member 'CompositeSourceOver'

I've got it almost working. However, the PNG image gets placed in the right spot but it is very very small. Like this:

[image]

The actual pixel dimensions of the PNG image are 31x38 but it gets scaled to around 7x9 in the output.

How can I disable the scaling?
Here's the code:

```
private func applyOverlay(existingBitMap : NSBitmapImageRep)  -> NSBitmapImageRep?
{
    var combinedImgRep : NSBitmapImageRep?
    
    guard
        let pngImg = NSImage(byReferencingFile: mOverlayPath!)
    else
    {
        print("Failed open overlay file: \(mOverlayPath!)")
        return combinedImgRep
    }
    
    let pngImgRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: pngImg.tiffRepresentation!)!;
    let pngWidth  = pngImgRep.pixelsWide
    let pngHeight = pngImgRep.pixelsHigh
    
    let newWidth  = mImgWidth + pngWidth + TEXT_MARGIN_RIGHT
    combinedImgRep = NSBitmapImageRep(
           bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
           pixelsWide: Int(newWidth),
           pixelsHigh: Int(mImgHeight),
           bitsPerSample: 8,
           samplesPerPixel: 4,
           hasAlpha: true,
           isPlanar: false,
           colorSpaceName: NSColorSpaceName.calibratedRGB,
           bytesPerRow: 0,
           bitsPerPixel: 0)!
            
    // copy original image to new blank
    copyImage(destImg: &combinedImgRep!, srcImg: existingBitMap, x: 0, y: 0)
    
    // copy overlay png image.  Center vertically
    let dstY = (existingBitMap.pixelsHigh - pngHeight) / 2
    copyImage(destImg: &combinedImgRep!, srcImg: pngImgRep, x: existingBitMap.pixelsWide, y: dstY)

    return combinedImgRep
}

// copy src to dest at the x,y position indicated
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468138/blend-two-nsimages-using-swift-on-os-x
private func copyImage(destImg : inout NSBitmapImageRep, srcImg: NSBitmapImageRep, x: Int, y: Int)
{
    let  destWidth = destImg.pixelsWide
    let destHeight = destImg.pixelsWide
    
    NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
    let nsContext = NSGraphicsContext.init(bitmapImageRep: destImg)
    NSGraphicsContext.current = nsContext
    let context = nsContext!.cgContext
    
    context.setFillColor(NSColor.blue.cgColor)
    context.fill(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: destWidth, height: destHeight))
    
    let  srcRect = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: srcImg.size)
    let destRect = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: destImg.size)
    let destPoint = NSPoint(x: x, y: y)

    srcImg.draw(at: destPoint)
    //srcImg.draw(in: destRect, from: srcRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.copy, fraction: 1.0, respectFlipped: true, hints: [:])
    //srcImg.draw(at: destPoint, from: srcRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.copy, fraction: 1.0)
    
    NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
}
```

**EDIT II**

Found it: the "scaling" was because the "size" reported by NSBitmapImageRep.size is not the same as the pixel dimensions.

Eg, `pngImage.pixelsWide` is 31 while `pngImage.size.width` is 7.999999. Why, I don't know.

Comment: Could you create a *new* (empty) image of the correct final dimensions, and then place *both* original images in their correct positions on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blend two NSImages using Swift on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468138/blend-two-nsimages-using-swift-on-os-x)

Comment: Willeke, that looks very close!  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
private func applyOverlay(existingBitMap : NSBitmapImageRep, boxString : inout String)  -> NSBitmapImageRep?
{
    var combinedImgRep : NSBitmapImageRep?
    
    guard
        let pngImg = NSImage(contentsOfFile: mOverlayPath!)
    else
    {
        print("Failed open overlay file: \(mOverlayPath!)")
        return combinedImgRep
    }
            
    let pngImgRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: pngImg.tiffRepresentation!)!;
    let pngWidth  = pngImgRep.pixelsWide
    let pngHeight = pngImgRep.pixelsHigh
    
    log(s: "applyOverlay - Loaded \(mOverlayPath!): \(pngWidth) x \(pngHeight)")
    
    let newWidth  = mImgWidth + pngWidth + TEXT_MARGIN_RIGHT
    combinedImgRep = NSBitmapImageRep(
           bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
           pixelsWide: Int(newWidth),
           pixelsHigh: Int(mImgHeight),
           bitsPerSample: 8,
           samplesPerPixel: 4,
           hasAlpha: true,
           isPlanar: false,
           colorSpaceName: NSColorSpaceName.calibratedRGB,
           bytesPerRow: 0,
           bitsPerPixel: 0)!
    
    print("applyOverlay - combinedImgRep \(combinedImgRep!.pixelsWide) x \(combinedImgRep!.pixelsHigh) bytes per row: \(combinedImgRep!.bytesPerRow)")
    
    // copy original image
    copyImage(destImg: &combinedImgRep!, srcImg: existingBitMap, x: 0, y: 0)
    
    // copy overlay png image.  Center vertically
    let dstY = (existingBitMap.pixelsHigh - pngHeight) / 2
    copyImage(destImg: &combinedImgRep!, srcImg: pngImgRep, x: existingBitMap.pixelsWide, y: dstY)

    return combinedImgRep
}

// copy src to dest at the x,y position indicated
private func copyImage(destImg : inout NSBitmapImageRep, srcImg: NSBitmapImageRep, x: Int, y: Int)
{
    let  destWidth = destImg.pixelsWide
    let destHeight = destImg.pixelsWide
    log(s: "copyImage - copy to (\(x), \(y)). Dest Size = \(destWidth) x \(destHeight) ")
    
    NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
    let nsContext = NSGraphicsContext.init(bitmapImageRep: destImg)
    NSGraphicsContext.current = nsContext
    let context = nsContext!.cgContext
    
    context.setFillColor(NSColor.blue.cgColor)
    context.fill(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: destWidth, height: destHeight))
    
    let  srcSize = NSSize(width: srcImg.pixelsWide, height: srcImg.pixelsHigh)
    let destRect = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: srcSize)

    srcImg.draw(in: destRect, from: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.copy, fraction: 1.0, respectFlipped: false, hints: nil)
    NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
}
```